# Change timestamp format used by env_logger

Tags: logging, rust, timestamp, format

The following minimal example

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate env_logger;

fn main() {
    std::env::set_var("MY_LOG_LEVEL", "info");
    env_logger::init_from_env("MY_LOG_LEVEL");
    info!("hi");
}
```

[outputs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3ca25a6aa9b279abef5c8de477c9b2e7&version=stable):

```
INFO 2018-02-18T09:59:20Z: playground: hi
```

I would like to use a different format (`"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.3f"`):

```
INFO 2018-02-18 09:59:20.123: playground: hi
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible¹.

While it is possible to use [`Formatter`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.5.3/env_logger/fmt/struct.Formatter.html) to change the format of the logged message, this formatter gives you the timestamp of the log message as a [`Timestamp`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.5.3/env_logger/fmt/struct.Timestamp.html). `Timestamp` only implements `Debug` and `Display`, with no extra methods. The documentation mentions no way to configure the way the date is displayed. It only mentions that the the class represents "An [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) formatted timestamp". This RFC defines the way to display a date. The format you want is not compatible with the RFC (most importantly, it's missing the timezone, please, *do not ever log datetimes without a timezone*, please).

The RFC does allow for more precision that what the crate currently uses. This feature was removed in a recent pull request titled ["Make the timestamp format more compact"](https://github.com/sebasmagri/env_logger/issues/36). In my opinion having more precision is sometimes useful and you could open an issue to ask for the `Timestamp` to allow that option. The RFC also does not allow the `T` between the date and the time to be omitted.

Looking at the implementation of the two traits ([`Debug`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.5.3/src/env_logger/fmt.rs.html#506-519) and [`Display`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.5.3/src/env_logger/fmt.rs.html#573-597)) shows that the representation is indeed fixed.

---

1: Well, you could just ignore the date from `env_logger`, and get your own if you really wanted to. I'm not sure how bad that would be.

Comment: I wonder if the precision format modifiers (`format!("{:.3}", time)`) could be used to opt into more precision in this case, or if that's too strange...

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible with `env_logger = "0.10"`.

Either

```rust
env_logger::builder()
    // setting this to None disables the timestamp
    .format_timestamp(Some(env_logger::TimestampPrecision::Millis))
    .init();
```

or

```rust
env_logger::builder()
    //.format_timestamp_secs()
    .format_timestamp_millis()
    //.format_timestamp_micros()
    //.format_timestamp_nanos()
    .init();
```

See [TimestampPrecision](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.10.0/env_logger/fmt/enum.TimestampPrecision.html) and [format_timestamp](https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.10.0/env_logger/struct.Builder.html#method.format_timestamp).

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Rust 1.45.2:

```rust
use chrono::Local;
use env_logger::Builder;
use log::LevelFilter;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    Builder::new()
        .format(|buf, record| {
            writeln!(
                buf,
                "{} {}: {}",
                record.level(),
                //Format like you want to: <-----------------
                Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.3f"),
                record.args()
            )
        })
        .filter(None, LevelFilter::Info)
        .init();

    log::warn!("warn");
    log::info!("info");
    log::debug!("debug");
}
```

More information: [Include timestamp in log messages](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/development_tools/debugging/config_log.html#include-timestamp-in-log-messages)

Comment: *Tested on stable channel 1.45.2* — this isn't the important piece of information. What would be more useful is what version of `env_logger` you are using.